# can not run ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

Tags: activexobject

I have an Application page which use ActiveX to execute an exe file installed on the client, but the code is working only when is allowed option in IE - "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" Enable

```
 <script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = Context.Request.Url.ToString();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", string.Format(@"RunEXE('{0}');", url), true);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "redir", string.Format(@"Redir('{0}');", Request.QueryString["Source"]), true);
    }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Main" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderMain" >
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

      function RunEXE(url) 
      {
          var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
          oShell.ShellExecute('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/SPMananager.exe', url, "", "open", 1);
      }

      function Redir(url) 
      {
          window.location = url;
      }  
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Shell.Application` is not marked as "safe for scripting" because it can be easily abused.

You don't want to visit a website that is able to break your Windows installation.

Comment: hm, so i tried link direct via hyperlink, but it did not work
 <a href="file:///C:/test/app/SPMananager.exe">Open</a></p>

Comment: I will add url with activex control to trusted sites ;-) but is it on intranet site